# JAXB unmarshalling of invalid integer

Tags: jaxb, cxf, unmarshalling

In our product we use apache CXF. Because of performance restriction, the schema validation has been set to false. Now, for an integer element if I am providing an invalid value, JAXB is unmarshaling it to some thing else. For example,

9999999999 is converted into 1410065407.

988888888888 is converted into 1046410808.

My question is what is the logic (formula) that is being followed here?

How to handle this (Considering the validation will be off)? I want such a value to be rejected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [JAXB (JSR-222)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

**SHORT ANSWER**

This appears to be a bug in the JAXB reference implementation.  I would recommend entering a bug for it at the following location:

- http://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB/

This same use case works correctly in EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy).

---

**LONG ANSWER**

Below is a complete example that demonstrates the issue:

***Root***

Below is a domain class with `int` and `integer` fields.

```java
package forum13216624;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    int int1;
    int int2;
    Integer integer1;
    Integer integer2;

}
```

***input.xml***

Below is an XML document with the values from your question.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <int1>9999999999</int1>
    <int2>988888888888</int2>
    <integer1>9999999999</integer1>
    <integer2>988888888888</integer2>
</root>
```

***Demo***

In the demo code below I've specified a `ValidationEventHandler` on the `Unmarshaller`.  This should catch a `ValidationEvent` for any invalid values encountered during an `unmarhsal` operation.

```java
package forum13216624;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new ValidationEventHandler() {

            @Override
            public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
                System.out.println(event.getMessage());
                return true;
            }}

        );
        File xml = new File("src/forum13216624/input.xml");
        Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        System.out.println(root.int1);
        System.out.println(root.int2);
        System.out.println(root.integer1);
        System.out.println(root.integer2);
    }

}
```

***Output - JAXB Reference Implementation***

This output matches the behaviour you are seeing.

```
1410065407
1046410808
1410065407
1046410808
```

***Output - EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)***

If you specify MOXy as your JAXB provider (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html) this use case works as expected.  You will get a `ValidationEvent` for each invalid value, and if the `ValidationEvent` is handled the field/property won't be set to a invalid value.

```
Exception Description: The object [9999999999], of class [class java.lang.String], from mapping [org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[int1-->int1/text()]] with descriptor [XMLDescriptor(forum13216624.Root --> [DatabaseTable(root)])], could not be converted to [class java.lang.Integer].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9999999999"

Exception Description: The object [988888888888], of class [class java.lang.String], from mapping [org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[int2-->int2/text()]] with descriptor [XMLDescriptor(forum13216624.Root --> [DatabaseTable(root)])], could not be converted to [class java.lang.Integer].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "988888888888"

Exception Description: The object [9999999999], of class [class java.lang.String], from mapping [org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[integer1-->integer1/text()]] with descriptor [XMLDescriptor(forum13216624.Root --> [DatabaseTable(root)])], could not be converted to [class java.lang.Integer].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9999999999"

Exception Description: The object [988888888888], of class [class java.lang.String], from mapping [org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[integer2-->integer2/text()]] with descriptor [XMLDescriptor(forum13216624.Root --> [DatabaseTable(root)])], could not be converted to [class java.lang.Integer].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "988888888888"
0
0
null
null
```

---

**POTENTIAL WORKAROUND**

If your fields/properties are of type `Integer` and you can switch from the JAXB reference implementation then you could create an `XmlAdapter` to do your own `Integer` to/from `String`  conversions.

***IntegerAdapter***

Below is an example of an `XmlAdapter` demonstrating how you could provide your own conversion logic.

```java
package forum13216624;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class IntegerAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Integer>{

    @Override
    public Integer unmarshal(String string) throws Exception {
        return Integer.valueOf(string);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Integer integer) throws Exception {
        return String.valueOf(integer);
    }

}
```

***package-info***

Using the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation at the package level means that the `XmlAdapter` will apply to all fields/properties of type `Integer` for classes in this package.

```java
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=IntegerAdapter.class, type=Integer.class)
package forum13216624;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
```

***Output***

Below is the updated output when the RI is used.  The `int` values are still wrong, but not the `Integer` values are `null` and `ValidationEvents` are produced as expected.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9999999999"
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "988888888888"
1410065407
1046410808
null
null
```

***For More Information***

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and-times.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying the issue! For our product, switching JAXB reference implementation may not be possible, but declaring the elements of type integer as string may be a potential solution.

Comment: @ArnabBiswas - You don't need to make your elements of type `string`.  Instead I was suggesting supplying your own `String`/`Integer` conversion logic via an `XmlAdapter`.  I've updated my answer with a complete example.

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry that I was not clear enough with my comment. But, this is what I am also considering.

Comment: Blaise Doughan - you were right. My concept on Adapter was not proper.